# In Spring boot, how to access Model attribute from jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, freemarker

Suppose I have an variable userRole variable defined in FooController.java

#### FooController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String root(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userRole", role);
    return "index";
}
```

And I have a template 'index.ftl' which in freemarker syntax:

#### index.ftl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getVarFromModel() {
  // How to access the 'userRole' var which is defined inside FooController.java ?
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't access Spring's model on a javascript code**,

the model is being processed right before your view is being rendered to client,
**by the time your client will receive the parsed HTML page**, your javascript won't be able to address the model because ***on that phase the model is not relevant***.

On the client you have only HTML CSS and javascript and other static content.

Comment: True, though OP might can get away with something like `var userRole = "${userRole?js_string}";`.

Comment: OP? What do you mean by that?